# Writing MYSQLI query results to a text file in php

Tags: php, html, mysqli

```
<body>

  <?php

    ini_set('display_errors', 1);
        ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
        error_reporting(E_ALL);


      $servername = "localhost";
      $username = "root";
      $password = "";
      $dbname = "random";

      // Create connection
      $conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
      // Check connection
      if (!$conn) {
          die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
      }

      $sql = "SELECT Channel_Location, Product, Active FROM channels
      ORDER BY RAND()
      Limit 5";
      $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
      if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
      // output data of each row
      while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
          $Channel_Location = $row['Channel_Location'];
          echo "<tr><br><td>".$Channel_Location."</td></tr>";

      }

      } else {
          echo "0 results";
      }

          $myfile = fopen("Log.txt", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
          $txt = "$result";
          fwrite($myfile, $txt);
          fclose($myfile);

      mysqli_close($conn);

?>

</body>
```

So basically my issue is i'm trying to write the output of `$result` to a text file but i get the following error

[image]

the text file should have 5 lines of text, if i change the `$txt = "$Channel_Location"` i will have one result but not all 5

Comment: Is there any reason to cache a mysqli object? If you wanna cache the rows, write these to a new array in the while loop and then `serialize` the array so you can write it to a file. On load you have to `unserialize` the string to get the array back.

Comment: How would i go about 'serialize' it ? new to this thank you in advance

Comment: just an observation: the html above is invalid ~ you have a `<br>` tag after the opening `<tr>` tag inside the loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  $output = '';
  $outputArray=[];
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
      $Channel_Location = $row['Channel_Location'];
      echo "<tr><br><td>".$Channel_Location."</td></tr>";
      $output .= $row['Channel_Location']."\n";
      $outputArray[] = $row;
  }

  file_put_contents('Log.txt',$output);

 // or you can use json_encode to save whole query result!!
 file_put_contents('log.txt',json_encode($outputArray));
```

Answer (score 0):

You must concatenate your data before writing the string to the file.

```
$text = '';
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $Channel_Location = $row['Channel_Location'];
    $text = $text . $Channel_Location . "\n";
}
```

You can then do something like:

```
fwrite($myfile, $text);
```

Answer (score 0):

`fwrite` writes a string to a document.

`$result` is an object and as such cannot be written as a string.

Your best option is when you run through the loop to print out the values, also add them to a string.

I would also recommend doing the `fwrite` function within the `if` statement as you will need values to write to it otherwise it will just open the file, write an empty variable and then close.

```
<?php

    ini_set('display_errors', 1);
    ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
    error_reporting(E_ALL);


    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "";
    $dbname = "random";

    // Create connection
    $conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    // Check connection
    if (!$conn) {
          die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
    }

    $sql = "SELECT Channel_Location, Product, Active FROM channels
    ORDER BY RAND()
    Limit 5";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
        $output = '';
        // output data of each row
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            $Channel_Location = $row['Channel_Location'];
            echo "<tr><br><td>".$Channel_Location."</td></tr>";
            $output .= $Channel_Location . '/n';
        }

        $myfile = fopen("Log.txt", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
        $txt = "$output";
        fwrite($myfile, $txt);
        fclose($myfile);

    } else {
      echo "0 results";
    }

    mysqli_close($conn);

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you want to user record

```
$output ='';
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $Channel_Location = $row['Channel_Location'];
        $output .="<tr><br><td>".$Channel_Location."</td></tr>";

    }

} else {
      $output .= "0 results";
}

$myfile = fopen("Log.txt", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
fwrite($myfile,$output);
fclose($myfile);

mysqli_close($conn);
```